# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '7' when i try to comapare the dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

Currently working on comparing the dates where if the first date has 4/12/2004 and second date as 12/12/2000  an alert should come second date should be greater than first date so i comparing the two dates like below code

```
 $.each(".wrk_exp", function(key, value) {
    console.log("Start Date: ", dateStart[key]);
    console.log("Start End: ", dateEnd[key]);
    if (($(".startDate", this) != null) && ($(".endDate", this) != null) && (dateStart[key] >= dateEnd[key])) {
      //alert('Date ranges overlap');
      alert("To date " + dateEnd[key] + " should be greater then from date " + dateStart[key]);
      valid = false;
      diffDays += parseInt((dateEnd[key] - dateStart[key]) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      console.log("diffdays", diffDays);
      return valid;
    }
  });
```

But I am getting an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '7' in .wrk_exp

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/q4zssncz/8/) for the same

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI: jQuery never returns `null`, it returns an empty collection if the elements aren't found ?

Comment: @adeneo thanks for the quick information so i have put ="" empty string not with null

Comment: Should be `if ( $(".endDate", this).length === 0 )`

Comment: But that's not really the issue here, sounds like you're passing in a string somewhere jQuery expects an object

Comment: yes because still the issue coming :(

Comment: @adeneo can you guide here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97670/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-adeneo).

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over a string, not elements, an array, or something that jQuery lets you iterate over

```
$.each(".wrk_exp", function() {...
```

That's a string, you probably wanted

```
$.each( $(".wrk_exp"), function() {...
```

or just

```
$(".wrk_exp").each(function() {...
```

which would be the more proper way to iterate over elements

Comment: hey hi thanks for the reply  now that error is not coming but the comparison is not happening kindly please help me what i am doing wrong

Comment: if (($(".startDate", this).length != 0) && ($(".endDate", this).length != 0) && (dateStart[key] >= dateEnd[key]))  i need to put some condition here it seems because when i select the from date i am getting an alert :(

Comment: That's some logical error you're making in your code. Also, you're returning `valid` from the `each()` function, which doesn't seem to make much sense,